# segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: 16.04

am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

After installing some applications I faced a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

What does it mean ? How can I resolve this issue ?

For example:

After installing orange3, when I launch it from terminal I experience this error.

Comment: segmentation fault means that some applications or libraries are failing hard, and crashing, which is what the segfault messages are.  What applications did you install and how did you install it?  (Because this usually doesn't happen_

Comment: "`segmentation fault`" means an out-of-bounds memory address, and is an application (or library) problem.  Look at `/var/crash/*.crash` for your coredump.

Comment: This seems rather a specific Software/Configuration problem and not directly related to Ubuntu

Comment: orange3 is [installed by default in Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYnlm.png), so I don't think it will seg fault in Anaconda.